# GetLastWin32Error returning int instead of uint

Tags: .net, pinvoke

If `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` exposes the `Win32` `GetLastError` function from `Kernel32.DLL` then why is it retuning an int, where as `GetLastError` is returning a DWORD which is unsigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because unsigned integers are not [CLS compliant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f.aspx).  In the early days, VB.NET and J# couldn't handle them, two out of the four supported languages.  That's been fixed, but there are still many languages around that can run on the CLR but don't supported unsigned integers, Java being the best known example.